# Сумма и среднее арифметическое последовательности положительных чисел

Tags: c++, visual-c++, инспекция-кода

Написать программу, вычисляющую сумму и среднее арифметическое последовательности положительных чисел, которые вводятся с клавиатуры(длина последовательности не ограничена). Для завершения ввода нужно нажать 0.
Проверьте правильность написания.  Возможно как то можно подредактировать?

```
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int a=0, summa=0, n=0;
    float srednee;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a == 0) break;
        summa += a;
        n++;
    }
    srednee = summa / n;
    cout << "Сумма и среднее соответственно: " << summa<<' '<<srednee;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Открываете среду/редактор, начинаете вводить `#include<`, нажимая соответствующие клавиши на клавиатуре... После всех нужных заголовочных файлов пишете `int main() {` - для такой программы, как у вас, можно не заморачиваться отдельными функциями - и вводите код, который "понимаете, как записать". Примерно так. Потом сохраняете, компилируете, исправляете ошибки...

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Кстати... Нарисуйте схему. Пусть не любят это делать люди, но будет вам хоть видно, что вы делаете...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, выскажу свое мнение.

```
float srednee;
```

Я бы предпочел использовать `double`. Но, в конце-концов...

```
while (true)
{
    cin >> a;
```

Наверное, стоило бы пояснить пользователю, что от него хотят, нет?

```
    if (a == 0) break;
```

И что ввод нуля означает завершение ввода...

```
srednee = summa / n;
```

А вот тут проблема. Поскольку вы делите `int` на `int`, деление - целочисленное, с отбрасыванием дробной части. Так что тут не "вкусовой" совет, а решительное требование приведения типа. Для простоты - как

```
srednee = float(summa) / n;
```

(не буду забивать вам голову `static_cast`).

Собственно, вроде бы и все.

Comment: Ещё надо учесть, что первым же введённым числом может оказаться 0. Можно спорить, какой вывод будет правильным в этом случае, но вряд ли это должно быть сообщение об аварийном завершении программы :)